# How to check whether a string contains several characters in GNU regular expression?

Tags: regex

Hi I want to check whether a string contains "abc" with GNU regular expression, I've tried `\b` and `\w` but neither of them works.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <regex.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
        regex_t regex;
        int reti;
        char msgbuf[100];

/* Compile regular expression */
        //reti = regcomp(&regex, "\wabc\w", 0);
        reti = regcomp(&regex, "\babc\b", 0);
        if( reti ){ fprintf(stderr, "Could not compile regex\n"); exit(1); }

/* Execute regular expression */
        reti = regexec(&regex, "123abc123", 0, NULL, 0);
        if( !reti ){
                puts("Match");
        }
        else if( reti == REG_NOMATCH ){
                puts("No match");
        }
        else{
                regerror(reti, &regex, msgbuf, sizeof(msgbuf));
                fprintf(stderr, "Regex match failed: %s\n", msgbuf);
                exit(1);
        }

/* Free compiled regular expression if you want to use the regex_t again */
    regfree(&regex);

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To search for the string `abc`, simply remove the `\b`, i.e.

```
    reti = regcomp(&regex, "abc", 0);
```

This will match, whereas `"\babc\b"` will only match `abc` enclosed with the backspace character. To match only the *word* `abc` (i.e. `123 abc 123`, but not `123 abc123` or `123abc123`), quote the backslash, as in

```
    reti = regcomp(&regex, "\\babc\\b", 0);
```